# inserting data to database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" value="name" id="name" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" /></p>

<script>
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        var text = $("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                text: text
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert("inserted");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and on page.php I have:

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST["text"]) {
    $servername = "server";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "passw";
    $dbname = "database";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo "sth is not right";
    }

    $text = $_REQUEST['text'];

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']? : ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']? : $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table`(`id`, `name`, `ip`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('', '$text', '$ip', '')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    echo "sth is not right";
}

$conn->close();
```

And... I approached 2 problems - the first one - nothing adds to the database. I get the popup from ajax saying: inserted, but that's all, no data is visible in database. The second problem is about the insert query - when I run it manually in sql developer, I get the error msg that there's a duplicate of a unique key, and I get it since the id that I'm passing is empty. But even if I hardcode there for one run some number (e.g. '33') - after clicking the button on the webpage there's still nothing in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would make sure your table's `id` is an identity field with something like an auto incrementing integer seeding value, then you should remove the id field from the `INSERT` statement completely because your database should manage this. I would also strongly suggest that you read about SQL injection, because this approach you are taking is not a good one. (see stovroz's answer for the params way)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insert values into id and timestamp (as opposed to inserting the value '') then don't have them in your query. Also, it's very important to use parameterized queries instead of string building, to prevent sql injection.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`name`, `ip`) VALUES (:text, :ip)";
$params = ["text" => $text, "ip" => $ip];
$conn->query($sql, $params);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution, but I still have some problems with ajax since the data is not in the database... What can be the issue?

Comment: Take ajax out the the equation and try hitting your page via the browser directly with a query string,  i.e. `/page.php?text=something` so you can see what's going on there first.

Answer (score 0):

You may not pass an empty value to the database - mysql so tries to fill an empty string.

Try

```
INSERT INTO database.table ('name','ip') VALUES ('$text','$ip');
```

Comment: use stovroz answer. Much better because it prevents SQL injection.